# Should HiddenFor respect DisplayFormat?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta, I have an entity with this property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:o}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public virtual DateTime SavedAt { get; set; }
```

In a view, generated with the "Controller with read/write actions and views, using EntityFramework" template, I have this code to create an editor for it:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SavedAt)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SavedAt)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SavedAt)
</div>
```

Which produces this output:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="SavedAt">SavedAt</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field SavedAt must be a date." data-val-required="The SavedAt field is required." id="SavedAt" name="SavedAt" type="text" value="2012-03-31T22:45:18.2244059" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SavedAt" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Notice that the date is formatted as "2012-03-31T22:45:18.2244059".

If I replace the view code fragment with this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SavedAt)
```

This code is generated:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field SavedAt must be a date." data-val-required="The SavedAt field is required." id="SavedAt" name="SavedAt" type="hidden" value="31/03/2012 22:45:18" />
```

Notice that the date is now formatted as "31/03/2012 22:45:18".

**The question is:**

Is HiddenFor expected to honor the formatting defined by the DisplayFormat attribute?

If not, what would be a good alternative to have the hidden field output in the desired format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is HiddenFor expected to honor the formatting defined by the DisplayFormat attribute?

No, it doesn't. Only the EditorFor and DisplayFor helpers use the DisplayFormat.

> If not, what would be a good alternative to have the hidden field
>   output in the desired format?

You shouldn't really care about the format of a hidden field. It's hidden, nobody sees it. But if for some reason you wanted a custom format you could override the default template with a custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/HiddenInput.cshtml`):

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml)
{
    @Html.Encode(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
}
@Html.Hidden("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```

And then decorate your view model property with the `[HiddenInput]` attribute to indicate that you want this to render as a hidden field:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:o}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public virtual DateTime SavedAt { get; set; }
```

And finally:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SavedAt)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. And by the way, the controller will see the value of the hidden field when the form is posted back. Actually, with the current format, the form doesn't even post back, because the date format is not recognized as a valid date, since it was output in DD/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: For consistency, I put all datetimes in round-trip format:
`@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime) || ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>) && ViewData.Model != null)
 {
  ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue = ((DateTime)ViewData.Model).ToString("O");
 }`
I added a custom model binder to adjust the incoming datetime to UTC:
`DateTime.TryParse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out other_value)`
This gave me the best chance of ASP.Net MVC maintaining the correct datetime value.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SavedAt)` it will prevent you from having to do a postback.

To avoid losing Date value, I'm using `TempData`, then I reassigned the model value at the `[HttpPost]`

Comment: That will work, but may not work in all cases. I solved this by using a view model and passing the value of the "Ticks" property back and forth instead of the DateTime.

Comment: Ticks could work or just format to an ISO 8601 string? (ToString("o"))